# Why mounting file systems is better design option than prefixing path names with a drive name or number?

Tags: unix, operating-system, filesystems

This is an exercise from "Modern Operating Systems" book. In introduction there's a paragraph about this question

> UNIX does not allow path names to be prefixed
>   by a drive name or number; that would be precisely the kind of device dependence
>   that operating systems ought to eliminate

Can someone give an example to show what kind of dependency it is?

Answer (score -1):

If this is an actual question in the book—

> Why mounting file systems is better design option than prefixing path names with a drive name or number?

—you need a different book to get a broader view of the world.The eunuch's system is a different way of doing things and it not necessarily a better one.

Non-eunuchs mainframe and mini systems typically use logical name translations so users do not actually even see the drive name/number.

Presumably the dependence they are referring to is having to code something to access "X:FILENAME", where X is a physical device. If the data moves to drive W: you then have to recode.

The question ignores systems that use logical device translation. They could use "ACCOUNTING_DATA:FILENAME" where ACCOUNTING_DATA is a logical device. Eunuch's would try to simulate something like that with symbolic links. However, the logical translation method is more flexible.

In short, it sounds like your book is rationalizing eunuch's idiosyncrasies as superior design.